# Why does default authentication backend of django calls set_password after raising UserModel.DoesNotExist exception?

Tags: python, django, authentication, exception, custom-authentication

I am writing a custom auth backend for a custom user model inherited from AbstractUser in django. I have gone through default auth backend of django and saw that user object is fetched using username with `UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)` authenticate() is as below

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
```

I have already written a custom aut backend, but I am asking this out of curiosity, Why is there a check on password upon a DoesNotExist exception?

I have tried `ipdb` in authenticate method and verified that upon getting username of a non-existing user, control flow goes to except block. And a `UserModel().set_password(password)` was issued in terminal. Being not sure what happens in the background, I inspected code of `set_password()` of `auth.models`. But it was just raising a `NotImplementedError` exception. I am not sure how this helps.

Also how to `raise a UserDoesNotExist or  django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist exception correctly` upon a failed object fetch operation on User Model in a custom auth backend? Idea is to stop the execution and present the user with the right feedback message instead of raising an exception and trying out next authentication backend as given in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS() in settings.py.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment explains exactly why. If it immediately returned False, it would take much less time than for a user that did not exist. An attacker would then be able to tell the difference between an existing and a non-existing username.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @daniel. But how does set_password returns a None on non-existing user? As mentioned in question it raises a not implemented exception.

Comment: That code instantiates an empty user just for the purposes of calling set_password.

Comment: Bit old question, but can anyone tell me if this is important if we take into account that the application allows everyone to register, meaning that attackers can use the register page to check for existing usernames?

Answer (score 4):

You should read this:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20760

> When attempting to authenticate using django.contrib.auth, if a user does not exist the authenticate() function returns None nearly instantaneously, while when a user exists it takes much longer as the attempted password gets hashed and compared with the stored password. This allows for an attacker to infer whether or not a given account exists based upon the response time of an authentication attempt.